# How to calculate max region/area of 2d circles?

Tags: collision-detection, collision-resolution

I have some 2d circles on a plane, each has its own minRadius and maxRadius. When two circles collides, both of them will shrink their radius, so the actual radius of a circle is in range [minRadius, maxRadius].

I need to calculate the max possible radius of each circle. See below image for an example.

[image]

Currently, I use the following algorithm to calculate the radius of each circle.
I try to increase each circle's radius a little each steps, then check and solve if there is any collisions.

```
foreach c in circles: c.radius = c.minRadius;

for (int i = 0; i < 10000; ++i)
{
  foreach c in circles: c.radius = c.radius + 1
  foreach c in circles: calculate_radius(c)
}

function calculate_radius(c)
  collides = find_all_circles_which_radius_is_overlap_with_c()

  foreach x in collides {
    x.radius -= somevalue;
    c.radius -= somevalue;
  }
end
```

For now, the result looks fine, but the algorithm costs too much time.

So I wonder if there exists other ways to solve it?

=======================================================

@wondra counterexample(maybe)

The image below illustrates the problem.

From my understanding of your algorithm, the final radius of circle A is 1.6, the calculation sequence is (BC, AB, AD)

But if using my algorithm(increase radius by a small amount each step), the final radius of circle A is 1.5.

I don't think recalculate the dist matrix after each selection will solve the problem, as stated in my question, each circle may have its own minRadius and max Radius.

[image]

Comment: Does those circles move? What is the reason for the 0 to 10000 cycle? Do I understand your code right - you expand each circle until it collides with other (and then keep expanding+reducing back remaining cycles)

Comment: On your picture, why are 3 bottom circles have different sizes, if you "grow" them equally. Do you need to start with all circles being the same size or are they different?

Comment: @wondra Yes, you are right, I try to expand them as much as they could. Some circles(only a few) can move around.

Comment: @KromStern I think it is because the way I calculate the radius. When collides happen, both circles' radius are reduced, so the middle circle's radius reduced more than the other two circles. Each circle may have its own min/max radius, but in the image above, all the circles have the same min/max radius.

Comment: I don't understand the scenario. It involves circles that have a minimum and maximum radius which sometimes collide and aren't allowed to overlap, but I'm confused what exactly the problem is and why you need to solve it.

Comment: @Anko All the circles starts with their minRaidus, then they start to expand their radius, they stop expanding once they reach their maxRadius or collide with other circles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets put together some greedy algorithm. If we had two circles(circle centers), the solution is trivial, right? Just calculate the distance(pythagoras) between them and divide it by two. 
But what if we had more? As you might agree, at least good solution, if not optimal, is always draw the smallest possible circles such as its radius is maximal possible.

```
while(hasCirclesToDraw)
draw(circles.GetSmallestCircle());
```

this information might not be helpful on its own, but if coupled with *how* to find such circle it will be working algorithm. If we had no circles drawn, which one will it be? The one* with center closest to other center (*actually this is pair of circles). 
What about the second one? It can be harder because you must consider the circle is already drawn and had closer neighbour. Well... it is not, just subtract its radius from the distance. Also you might cache the distances calculated.

```
int[][] distMatrix;
for(int i = 0; i < circles.count; i++)
{
    Pair<int,int> edge = findShortest(distMatrix); // ignore -1 edges
    if(!circles[edge.first].hasRadius())
    {
    if(circles[edge.second].hasRadius())
        circles[edge.first].radus = distMatrix[edge.first, edge.second] - circles[edge.second].radius;
    else
        circles[edge.first].radus  = distMatrix[edge.first, edge.second] / 2;
    }
else if(){
    //i believe you can finish it for second circle of pair
}
    distMatrix[edge.first, edge.second] = -1; //"remove edge"
}
```

You can also optimize this by drawing any circles that doesnt have any other nearby (within double max radius) and removing them from the list before begining. Or ignore all big distances right away. You could also use priority queue instead of calculating distance/distance array - sort once and then only pop.
obviously, this will not work for extreme numbers of circles, because it requires n^2 space and the whole algorithm is n^3.
To illustrate the algorithm first steps (for ilustration purposes, the longes edges are not drawn at all):

1. find shortest edge, add two new circles(because on both ends there was nothing drawn). Remove edge (=mark -1)
2. find shortest edge, add only one new circle, because it already had circle drawn on one end. Remove edge (=mark -1)
3. step would be: find shortest edge(now the left most), do nothing, because on both end there is a circle. Remove edge (=mark -1)

[image: circles]

Comment: Very interesting idea, but I think there is some counterexample, please take a look at my updated post.

Comment: @lostyzd I dont think it is counterexample. It it just how greedy algorithms work - they produce at least "good" solution and this behaviour is much expected. Not even mentioning it is strongly subjective whether is better solution with 1.6 and 1.4 circles or two 1.5 circles. Or was there other problem with the solution?

Comment: You can also get your proposed result by modifying the algorithm to take the edges with no circles on the end first.